# in the oupout i don't have space between the words where is the problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def convert(str):
    l=""
    for i in str:
        if i.isupper():
            l+=i.lower()
        elif i.islower():
              l+=i.upper()
    return l
print(convert("Hello Word"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not considering the case of characters that are not letters, this will do the trick

```
def convert(str):
    l=""
    for i in str:
        if i.isupper():
            l+=i.lower()
        elif i.islower():
              l+=i.upper()
        else:
          l+=i
    return l
str="Python is a Programming Language "
print(convert(str))
```

Answer (score -1):

You did not consider where the object is not a letter. Therefore, the code must be:

```
def convert(str):
    l=""
    for i in str:
        if i.isupper():
            l+=i.lower()
        elif i.islower():
             l+=i.upper()
        elif i.isalpha()==False:
             l+=i
    return l
print(convert("Hello World"))
```

Then the output will be:

```
hELLO wORLD
```